# linq,js GroupBy coordinates(lat, lng)

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq.js

I have the following array:

```
var coord = [
{flat:"7", house:"14", indication1: "60", lat: "47.93896450", lng:"33.43282100"},
{flat:"9", house:"18", indication1: "65", lat: "47.87736800", lng:"33.27488850"},
{flat:"10", house:"14", indication1: "24", lat: "47.93896450", lng:"33.43282100"},
{flat:"11", house:"14", indication1: "11", lat: "47.93896450", lng:"33.43282100"},
{flat:"12", house:"14", indication1: "56", lat: "47.93896450", lng:"33.43282100"}];
```

I want to use linq.js to group these array by two fields: `lat` and `lng`.

```
var h = Enumerable.From(data).GroupBy(
            "{lat: $.lat, lng: $.lng}",
            "{ House: $.house, Flat: $.flat }",
            "{ Qlat: $.lat, Qlng: $.lng, info: $$.ToArray()}").ToArray();

console.log(h);
```

I expected to see 2 groups, but got all 5. Where was I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use an object for grouping. Every new generated object is a new object and not equal to the last or any other object.

You could take `null` as first parameter and the string with grouping information as fourth parameter.

```js
var coord = [{ flat: "7", house: "14", indication1: "60", lat: "47.93896450", lng: "33.43282100" }, { flat: "9", house: "14", indication1: "65", lat: "47.87736800", lng: "33.27488850" }, { flat: "10", house: "14", indication1: "24", lat: "47.93896450", lng: "33.43282100" }, { flat: "11", house: "14", indication1: "11", lat: "47.93896450", lng: "33.43282100" }, { flat: "12", house: "14", indication1: "56", lat: "47.93896450", lng: "33.43282100" }],
    grouped = Enumerable.From(coord).GroupBy(
        null,
        "{ House: $.house, Flat: $.flat }",
        "{ Qlat: $.lat, Qlng: $.lng, info: $$.ToArray()}",
        "$.lat + '|' + $.lng"
    ).ToArray();

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's cool, but how I can set the coordinates as array key? `[Qlat, Qlng] => {info[]}`

Comment: i do not understand, what you need. please add an example result to the question.